# Creating selfextracting zips in php on the fly

Tags: php, zip, sfx

I'm working on a php script packaging some files (a setup.exe and a licence.txt which is created direct in php for the user). We don't want that the user has to unzip it and start setup.exe. 
On the computer we solved that by using selfextracting zips with:

zip is called setup.exe
zip has icon of the application
destination of extraction is temporary folder
extracting process is hidden

So if the user click on setup.exe he don't know that this setup.exe is a zip at the end.

But is that also possible on the server in the php script?
i tried the normal ziparchive object and pclzip and i can create the zip with these libraries. But i cannot change the parameters above...

Can anyone tell me if there's a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Use [PHP:exec](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php) to run an external application that compress and compile your exec file, with your stuff inside as you need.

PHP don't have built-in function to compress and compile and executable file.

Comment: Is there no other solution? no lib that can do that?
We don't know on which server this script will run, so we don't know if exec is allowed there...

Comment: as I said, no built-in... Maybe if you search you can find some library to help you with that, but I don't think that someone spend time re-creating the wheel when you can just run an external program that does it very well...